# Undefined property: stdClass::$images

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In products table I have image row which stores images of every product and looks like this in database `["4.jpg","5.jpg"]` in each product. Now I want to display the product and the images which belongs to that product in the view but am stuck it shows an error `Undefined property: stdClass::$images` how can I fix this ?

Here are the codes

blade view

```
   @foreach($products as $product)
   @foreach($product->images as $image)
      <img src="{{url('images',$image->filepath)}}" alt="">
     @endforeach
     @endforeach
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{ 

$Input=$request->all();
$image=array();
if($files=$request->file('image')){
    foreach($files as $file){
        $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('images',$name);
        $image[]=$name;

    }

} 
 product::create(array_merge($Input,
 [
'image' => json_encode($image),

])); 
return redirect()->back(); 

}
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: How are you generating `$products`?  What is the dump from that variable?

Comment: I'm generating the product from here `product::create(array_merge($Input,
 [
'image' => json_encode($image),

]));`  @Watercayman

Answer (score 0):

In the controller you're saving it under `image`:

```
'image' => json_encode($image),
```

but in the view you're reading from `images`:

```
@foreach($product->images as $image)
```

so I'm guessing that should be `$product->image`. You didn't post the controller that renders the view so I'm guessing here.

Comment: That gives an error `"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` @swordbeta

Comment: @user11710915 did you json_decode it beforehand? You can not loop over a string. If you did not: `@foreach(json_decode($product->image) as $image)` might do it.

Comment: Yeah I did before and it was not working @swordbeta

Comment: I tried that json_decode and I got the error `Property [image] does not exist on this collection instance.` @swordbeta

Answer (score 0):

for the error you're getting, I think it's because your product table has `image` as an attribute and you're trying to retrieve the images using `images` as a key.

you're implementing a bad design for your application by storing the images as an array.

since you have multiple images create a new table `images` with product_id as a foreign key.

```php
Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->dateTime('created_at');
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

now, on your products and image modals add the relationships.

```php
/* add this on your Product.php modal */
public function images()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
}
```

```php
/* add this on your Image.php modal */
public function product()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
```

now, to retrieve all images related to a certain product, you just need to call

```php
@foreach($product->images() as $image)
      <img src="{{url('images',$image->filepath)}}" alt="">
@endforeach
```

Comment: It is not storing images in image table, it stores image in the product->image row @Djellal Mohamed Aniss

Comment: i know, and i am advising you to create a separate table for your case

Comment: I did this before, I created images table and made relation with products but didn't know how to display them in the database so I asked a question and someone gave that `json_encode` answer now I have both `json_encode` and images relate to product but not working @Djellal Mohamed Aniss

Comment: The `json_encode` display images in database but doesn't show them in the view but the (images->relation) can't store image in images table I don't know why @Djellal Mohamed Aniss